# Map conversion inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is example of mylist for input:

```
mylist = [['RWILY MORSHED', 7670315350025, 'August/2014, Iulie/2014, Septembrie/2014', 1620, 1620], ['AL BADRI MOHAMMED YAHYA TAWFEEQ', 7700119350028, 'Martie/2015, Aprilie/2015, Februarie/2015', 1620, 1620]]
```

and my desired output will be this:

```
mylist = [['RWILY MORSHED', 7670315350025, 'August 2014, July 2014, September 2014', 1620, 1620], ['AL BADRI MOHAMMED YAHYA TAWFEEQ', 7700119350028, 'March 2015, April 2015, February 2015', 1620, 1620]]
```

Basically I want to convert the months names from Romanian to English and get the above desired output(I need all the month in the same index 2 position like in output)!

And to that I ended up with this:

```
conversionsEnNames = {"Ianuarie": "January", "Februarie": "February","Martie": "March", "Aprilie": "April","Mai": "May","Iunie": "June", "Iulie": "July","August": "August", "Septembrie": "September","Octombrie": "October", "Noiembrie": "November","Decembrie": "December"}

for i in mylist:
    i[2]=i[2].replace("/", " ")
    for j in i:
        if j in conversionsEnNames:
            j = conversionsEnNames[j]
            i[2]=j

print(mylist)
```

But that will print:

```
[['RWILY MORSHED', 7670315350025, 'August 2014, Iulie 2014, Septembrie 2014', 1620, 1620], ['AL BADRI MOHAMMED YAHYA TAWFEEQ', 7700119350028, 'Martie 2015, Aprilie 2015, Februarie 2015', 1620, 1620]]
```

And for sure the map won't work since 'Iulie 2014' != 'Iulie' so that it can convert it to July, what I to modify in order to achieve my disired output? Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: try replace `j = conversionsEnNames[j]; i[2]=j` with `i[2].replace(j, conversionsEnNames[j])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should do it.

```
for item in mylist:
    item[2] = item[2].replace('/', ' ')
    for roman, english in conversionsEnNames.items():
        item[2] = item[2].replace(roman, english)
```

Comment: This seems the most easy and fast approach, thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use regular expressions (just because regexes are cool, not because the solution is better than the others). Here's a snippet that takes care of the replacement in a single string:

```
import re
def rep(m):
    if m.group(1) in conversionEnNames:
        return conversionEnNames[m.group(1)] + " " + m.group(2)
    else:
        return m.group(0)
test = "blah blah Iulie/2014 blah Februarie/2015 blih blah bluh"
result = re.sub(r"([A-Za-z]+)/(\d\d\d\d)", rep, test)
```

It should yield

```
"blah blah July 2014 blah February 2015 blih blah bluh"
```

You can improve on that as needed.

Comment: I also like regex, need to study them more thou, I also like this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use a simple dict lookup

```
def convert_date(date_string, conversionsEnNames):

    parts = [part.split('/') for part in date_string.split(', ')]
    return ', '. join(conversionsEnNames[part[0]] + ' ' + part[1] for part in parts)

for line in mylist:
    line[2] = convert_date(line[2], conversionsEnNames)
```

> ```
> mylist
> ```

```
[['RWILY MORSHED', 7670315350025, 'August 2014, July 2014, September 2014', 1620, 1620], 
['AL BADRI MOHAMMED YAHYA TAWFEEQ', 7700119350028, 'March 2015, April 2015, February 2015', 1620, 1620]]
```

Comment: Thank you! I will test this!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the last three lines in the loop.

```
>>> for i in mylist:
...     i[2]=i[2].replace("/", " ")
...     for j in conversionsEnNames:
...         i[2] = i[2].replace(j, conversionsEnNames[j])
... 
>>> print(mylist)
[['RWILY MORSHED', 7670315350025, 'August 2014, July 2014, September 2014', 1620, 1620], ['AL BADRI MOHAMMED YAHYA TAWFEEQ', 7700119350028, 'March 2015, April 2015, February 2015', 1620, 1620]]
```

Comment: Thank you, I will also try this!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful: `i` is not the "months" string, but the whole list.

Hence `"Iulie"` does not belong to the list (but is a substring of an element in the list).

Moreover, you can use `.replace(x, conversionsEnNames[x])` for each `x` in `conversionsEnNames`: this is not "safe" (why?), but it works, in this case.